# Functions for properties

Tags: vb.net

I want to make something similar to the listbox.children property. I know I can write this to return the children of the listbox:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Children(index as integer)
   Get
      'Return the children at the specified index
   End Get     
End Property
```

But how I can make the functions for the Children property? For example List.Children.Count would return the count of the list entries but List.Children(0) would return the first entry.

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source code file.  The changes you have to make to get this code to compile will help you find the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually pretty simple. I just had to make this function:

```
Public Function GetItem(Of T)(index as integer) as T
 Return _ListOfT(index)
End Functions
```

And then just modify the T class to suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the type of your Children property to something that implements the [IEnumerable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx), such as a List(of Child) to easily get Count, For Each iteration, etc.  Currently you are returning an Integer, but my guess is that there is a lot more to a "Child" entity than just a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but if you are asking how do you do something other than return a simple backing store, here goes:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Children(index as integer) as List(Of WhateverObject)
   Get
     return GetChildren(index)
   End Get     
End Property

Private Function GetChildren(index as integer) as List(Of WhateverObject)

'Code that actually gets a list of the object type of the children at that index

End Function
```

You can also put whatever code you want in the property itself, although I recommend calling a method.

Answer (score -1):

I think that '**list.children(0)**' is not a function, rather its a derived class with overloaded constructor or some like that. Apart from this you write a function which returns an array of that list type containing all child info.

Like,

```
public function ReturnChild(byval listbox as listbox, byref NewlistBox as listbox)

         your code goes here

end function
```